# Необходимо определить тип фигуры и рассчитать ее площадь

Tags: python, python-3.x, геометрия

На входе дается тип фигуры (квадрат или круг) и число, обозначающее радиус или длину стороны. Необходимо определить тип фигуры и рассчитать ее площадь
Input Format
Название фигуры на английском языке (Square или Circle), пробел и целое или десятичное число, обозначающее длину стороны квадрата или радиус круга

Я не смог разобраться как написать код так чтобы авто компилятор принял

```py
figure = input("Выберите фигуру (Square, Circle): ")
if figure == 'Square':
     print("Длины сторон :")
     a = float(input("a = "))
     print("Площадь:", a ** 2)
elif figure == 'Circle':
     r = float(input("Радиус круга R = "))
     import math
     print("Площадь: %.2f" % (math.pi*r**2))
```

нужно выполнить с использованием

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
input_data = input()
```

Comment: зачем определять тип, если он дается?

Comment: там авто компилятор и он задает по очереди Square 5.0 и потом Circle 3.0

Answer (score 1):

По описанию задачи (и входным данным!!!) тип фигуры и число даются ОДНОВРЕМЕННО. Поэтому надо введенную строку разделить на два параметра и потом уже вычислять результат:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    input_data = input()
    figure = input_data.split()[0]
    dim = float(input_data.split()[1])
    if figure == 'Square':
        print("Площадь:", dim**2)
    elif figure == 'Circle':
        import math
        print("Площадь: %.2f" % (math.pi*dim**2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

figure = input("Выберите фигуру (Square, Circle): ")

if figure == 'Square':
    a = float(input("Длина стороны = "))
    result = (f'Площадь квадрата со стороной {a} равна:{a**2}')
    print(result) 
elif figure == 'Circle':
    r = float(input("Радиус круга = "))
    result = (f'Площадь круга радиусом {r} равна:{math.pi*r**2}')
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я понял что вы имеете ввиду:

```py
import math

figure = input("Выберите фигуру (Square, Circle): ")

if figure == 'Square':
    a = float(input("a = "))
    print("Площадь:", a ** 2)

elif figure == 'Circle':
    r = float(input("Радиус круга R = "))
        print("Площадь: " + format(math.pi * r ** 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import pi
figure = input("Выберите фигуру (Square, Circle): ")
if figure =='Square':
  a=float(input("Длины сторон: "))
  print(a**2)
elif figure == "Circle":
  r=float(input("Радиус круга R = "))
  print("Площадь круга =",  pi*r**2)
else:
  print('Wrong parameter')
```